# Creating a relationship between two tables with a Composite Primary Key in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I've a database in SQLServer 2008.

I've a table "Table1" with three rows as the primary key and I need to create a relationship with another table "Table2" but I don't want to add the three fields of Table1 in Table2 to be able to create the relationship.

So I've added a new field in Table1 named IdRow of type Int and Indentity=yes and I've created an index of type "Unique Key" for this new field so I can create the relationship based on this new field instead the three others.

So far so good but when I import the two tables into the model in the Entity Framework's model it doesn't recognize the IdRow as unique so I can't create the relationship with Table2 based on this field.

Can someone help me with this?

Is there a workaround to solve this or I've to add the three fields of Table1 in Table2 to create the relationship?

Comment: try adding the relation in the EDMX model

Comment: Raphaël Althaus is right. Try to update your EDMX from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would do the opposite.

Can't you put the new idRow as the primary key, and add a UNIQUE Constraint on your 3 other fields ?

Comment: Thank you @Raphael. It works! but I don't know why if you don't add the primary key then the UNIQUE Constraint doesn't work